# How to pass through arguments and apply to function?

Tags: javascript, arguments, pass-through

I've got an `Uint8Array` on which I want to use the `slice` method.

So I took advantage of the array slice method like this:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(array, start, end);
```

Now I want to outsource some common used functions like this.
I  tried it with

```js
var utils = {
   slice: function() {
     return Array.prototype.slice.apply(this, arguments);
   }
};
```

But apparently I misunderstood how it really works. Can anybody explain this to me and how to achieve it to get working?

Comment: `utils.slice.call(array, start, end)`.

Comment: @Rocket I posted my last comment to fast, this is actually a good solution too, but I wanted to keep it as collection of methods and to call it with `.call` would be confusing. But thanks, helps me lot to understand javascript!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in that `this` is not what you think it is. If you call `utils.slice(foo, 1, 2)`, `this` will be `utils`.

Depending on how you want to call it, you could pass the object you want to operate on as first argument, then you would do:

```
var utils = {
   slice: function() {
     // The object we're operating on
     var self = arguments[0];
     // The rest of the arguments
     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

     return Array.prototype.slice.apply(self, args);
   }
};
```

Usage:

```
var someSlice = utils.slice(someArray, 2, 14);
```

Another (perhaps clearer) option is to just use named arguments:

```
var utils = {
    slice: function(array, from, to) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(array, from, to);
    }
};
```

This will work the same way.

**Update:** I got curious why `Uint8Array` doesn't have `slice`, and I found out about [`subarray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Int8Array#subarray%28%29):

```
Int8Array subarray(
  long begin,
  optional long end
);
```

Note that

> Note: Keep in mind that this is creating a new view on the existing buffer; changes to the new object's contents will impact the original object and vice versa.

It might be the case that this is what you want -- I'm betting on it being a lot more efficient -- if you don't need to copy the data, that is!

Comment: Aah, I understand the problem now! Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @DanLee: Glad to be of help! You might want to take a look at my note about `subarray`.

Comment: @Linus_G_Thiel: Magnificent! Why wasn't I as curious as you? Thanks a lot for your input, means a lot to me. Now I will dig deeper